# Audio file with different levels of volume

Tags: ios

I want the user to play audio, change the volume in some parts, and then save that file with the new levels of volume.

I changed the volume of an audio with AVAssetExportSession and AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters and worked, the problem is that I need create a audio loop with this audio, so first I created this loop and then I need change the volume

Here is my code

```
let type = "m4a"
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("mixedAudio.m4a")
var backgroundUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("background.m4a")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    playButotn.isEnabled = false

    let mainUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "prueba1", withExtension: type, subdirectory: "Audios")
    let mainDurations = AVAsset(url: mainUrl!).duration
    let secondAudioUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "walk", withExtension: type, subdirectory: "Audios")
    let backgroundDuration = AVAsset(url: secondAudioUrl!).duration

    if mainDurations > backgroundDuration {
        var times = Int(mainDurations.seconds / backgroundDuration.seconds)
        let rem = mainDurations.seconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: backgroundDuration.seconds)
        if rem > 0 {
            times = times + 1
        }

        createLoopAudio(times: times) {
            self.createFade {
                self.createMix(mainUrl: mainUrl!, backgroundUrl: self.backgroundUrl)
            }

        }
    }else {
        backgroundUrl = secondAudioUrl!
        createMix(mainUrl: mainUrl!, backgroundUrl: backgroundUrl)
    }

}


func createMix(mainUrl: URL, backgroundUrl: URL){
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let mainAsset = AVAsset(url: mainUrl)
    let backgroundAsset = AVAsset(url: backgroundUrl)
    let mainDurations = AVAsset(url: mainUrl).duration

    let mainAudioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    let backgroundAudioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

    let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mainDurations)

    do {
        try mainAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: mainAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)
        try backgroundAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: backgroundAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)
    }catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)

    assetExport?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    assetExport?.outputURL = documentsDirectory
    assetExport?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true


    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: documentsDirectory.path) {
        try! FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: documentsDirectory.path)
    }

    assetExport?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        switch assetExport!.status
        {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
            print("failed \(assetExport?.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
            print("cancelled \(assetExport?.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.unknown:
            print("unknown\(assetExport?.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.waiting:
            print("waiting\(assetExport?.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.exporting:
            print("exporting\(assetExport?.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed:
            print("complete")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.playButotn.isEnabled = true
            }
        }
    })

}


func createLoopAudio(times: Int, completion: @escaping () -> Void){

    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    var nextTimeStartClip = kCMTimeZero
    for _ in 1...times {

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "walk", withExtension: type, subdirectory: "Audios")
        let audioAsset = AVAsset(url: url!)

        print("tracks walk \(audioAsset.tracks.count)")
        let audioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
        let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration)

        do {
            try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: audioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0], at: nextTimeStartClip)
        }catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }



        nextTimeStartClip = CMTimeAdd(nextTimeStartClip, audioAsset.duration)
    }

    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)

    assetExport?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    assetExport?.outputURL = backgroundUrl
    assetExport?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: backgroundUrl.path) {
        try! FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: backgroundUrl.path)
    }

    assetExport?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        switch assetExport!.status
        {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
            print("failed \(assetExport?.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
            print("cancelled \(assetExport?.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.unknown:
            print("unknown\(assetExport?.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.waiting:
            print("waiting\(assetExport?.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.exporting:
            print("exporting\(assetExport?.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed:
            print("loop complete")
            completion()

        }
    })

}


func createFade(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let exportAudioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
    let audioAsset = AVAsset(url: backgroundUrl)

    let exportAudioMixInputParameters = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: audioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0])


    let start = 2
    let length = 3

    exportAudioMixInputParameters.setVolume(0.0, at: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(start - 1), 1))
    exportAudioMixInputParameters.setVolume(0.1, at: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(start), 1))
    exportAudioMixInputParameters.setVolume(0.5, at: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(start + 1), 1))
    exportAudioMixInputParameters.setVolume(1.0, at: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(start + 2), 1))

    exportAudioMixInputParameters.setVolume(1.0, at: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(start + length - 2), 1))
    exportAudioMixInputParameters.setVolume(0.5, at: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(start + length - 1), 1))
    exportAudioMixInputParameters.setVolume(0.1, at: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(start + length), 1))

    exportAudioMix.inputParameters = [exportAudioMixInputParameters]


    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    print("tracks loop \(audioAsset.tracks.count)")

    let audioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration)

    do {
        try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: audioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)
    }catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }



    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)

    assetExport?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
    assetExport?.outputURL = backgroundUrl
    assetExport?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: backgroundUrl.path) {
        try! FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: backgroundUrl.path)
    }

    assetExport?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        switch assetExport!.status
        {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
            print("failed \(assetExport?.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
            print("cancelled \(assetExport?.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.unknown:
            print("unknown\(assetExport?.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.waiting:
            print("waiting\(assetExport?.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.exporting:
            print("exporting\(assetExport?.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed:
            print("faded complete")
            completion()

        }
    })
```

Comment: This is a broad task you've given us

Comment: Do the volume changes have to happen if the file is moved to another app, or only when it's played back within your app?

Comment: Yes , I wan to save the audio with that ranges of volume

Comment: How i said, I can change the volume of a audio, the problem is when a created a loop with the audio and after put the volume leves cause when you set the levels of volume affect one track and when I create the loop file inside has 7 tracks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Found a way and works fine: I have 2 audios; A and B, B lasts less than A, so I create a loop of B to fit A, Then I play 2 audios at same time and with a slider I modify the volume of b. Finally I save this volume configuration and mix the audios. This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var playButotn: UIButton!

    var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    var podcastPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    var  times = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var volumeSlider: UISlider!

    var volumeRanges = [VolumeRange]()

    let type = "m4a"
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("mixedAudio.m4a")
    var backgroundUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("background.m4a")
    var mainUrl: URL?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mainUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "prueba1", withExtension: type, subdirectory: "Audios")

        playButotn.isEnabled = false

        volumeSlider.value = 1

        let mainDurations = AVAsset(url: mainUrl!).duration
        print(AVAsset(url: mainUrl!).duration.seconds)
        let secondAudioUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "rocking", withExtension: type, subdirectory: "Audios")
        let backgroundDuration = AVAsset(url: secondAudioUrl!).duration

        if mainDurations > backgroundDuration {
            times = Int(mainDurations.seconds / backgroundDuration.seconds)
            let rem = mainDurations.seconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: backgroundDuration.seconds)
            if rem > 0 {
                times = times + 1
            }

            createLoop(times: times) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.playButotn.isEnabled = true
                }
            }
        }else {
            backgroundUrl = secondAudioUrl!
            createMix()
        }

    }




    func createMix(){
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        let mainAsset = AVAsset(url: mainUrl!)
        let backgroundAsset = AVAsset(url: backgroundUrl)
        let mainDurations = AVAsset(url: mainUrl!).duration

        let mainAudioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
        let backgroundAudioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

        let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mainDurations)
        do {
            try mainAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: mainAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)
            try backgroundAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: backgroundAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)
        }catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)
        assetExport?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
        assetExport?.outputURL = documentsDirectory
        assetExport?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: documentsDirectory.path) {
            try! FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: documentsDirectory.path)
        }
        assetExport?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            switch assetExport!.status
            {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                print("failed \(assetExport?.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                print("cancelled \(assetExport?.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.unknown:
                print("unknown\(assetExport?.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.waiting:
                print("waiting\(assetExport?.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.exporting:
                print("exporting\(assetExport?.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed:
                print("mix complete")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.playButotn.isEnabled = true
                }

            }
        })

    }


    func createLoop(times: Int, completion: @escaping () -> Void){
        let urlFondo = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "rocking", withExtension: type, subdirectory: "Audios")
        let  acentoFile = try! JUMAudioFile(forReading: urlFondo!)
        let acentoPCM = acentoFile.getPCMArrayBufferFromURL()
        let (_ , acentoCompleteData) = JUMAudioFile.convertToPoints(arrayFloatValues: acentoPCM)
        var newDraft = [Float]()
        for _ in 1...times {
            for array in acentoCompleteData {
                for fl in array {
                    newDraft.append(fl)
                }
            }
        }

        let _ = try! JUMAudioFile(createFileFromFloats: [newDraft], url: self.backgroundUrl)
        print("loop complete")
        completion()

    }

    func createLoopAudioWithFade(completion: @escaping () -> Void){
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        let exportAudioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
        var exportAudioMixInputParametersArry =  [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters]()
        let audioAsset = AVAsset(url: self.backgroundUrl)
        let audioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
        let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration)
        do {
            try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: audioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)
        }catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        let exportAudioMixInputParameters = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: audioTrack)
        for ranges in volumeRanges {
            exportAudioMixInputParameters.setVolume(ranges.volume!, at: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(ranges.start!, 50000))
        }
        exportAudioMixInputParametersArry.append(exportAudioMixInputParameters)
        exportAudioMix.inputParameters = exportAudioMixInputParametersArry
        let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)

        assetExport?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
        assetExport?.outputURL = backgroundUrl
        assetExport?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: backgroundUrl.path) {
            try! FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: backgroundUrl.path)
        }

        assetExport?.audioMix = exportAudioMix
        assetExport?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            switch assetExport!.status
            {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                print("failed \(assetExport?.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                print("cancelled \(assetExport?.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.unknown:
                print("unknown\(assetExport?.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.waiting:
                print("waiting\(assetExport?.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.exporting:
                print("exporting\(assetExport?.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed:
                print("fade complete")
                completion()

            }
        })

    }




    @IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {
        do{

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: backgroundUrl)
            player?.prepareToPlay()
            player?.volume = 1.0



            podcastPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: mainUrl!)
            podcastPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
            podcastPlayer?.volume = 1


            podcastPlayer?.play()
            player?.play()
        }catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }


    @IBAction func changeVolume(_ sender: UISlider) {
        if (player?.isPlaying)!{
        player?.volume = sender.value
        let volumeRange = VolumeRange()
        volumeRange.volume = sender.value
        volumeRange.start = player?.currentTime
        volumeRanges.append(volumeRange)
        }
    }


    @IBAction func touchUp(_ sender: UISlider) {
    }

    @IBAction func touchUpOutside(_ sender: UISlider) {
        print("ouside")
    }


    @IBAction func generar(_ sender: Any) {

        playButotn.isEnabled = false

        self.createLoopAudioWithFade() {
            self.createMix()

        }
    }

    @IBAction func playMix(_ sender: UIButton) {
        do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: documentsDirectory)
        player?.prepareToPlay()
        player?.volume = 1.0
            player?.play()
        }catch {

        }
    }


}


class VolumeRange {
    var volume: Float?
    var start: Double?
}
```